# how to make a custom op command in Minecraft

Tags: java, plugins, jar, minecraft

I was wondering how to make a custom command within a .jar plugin that gives the specified player operator status.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Create a plugin such as explained in [official spigot wiki](https://www.spigotmc.org/wiki/creating-a-blank-spigot-plugin-in-eclipse/?noRedirect=1) or [here](https://mcreator.net/wiki/how-make-spigot-plugin)
2. Create a new command such as explained in [official spigot wiki](https://www.spigotmc.org/wiki/create-a-simple-command/)
3. When player run command, use `player.setOp(true);`

Full command example (have to be runned as console) :

```java
@Override
public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command command, String label, String[] args) {
   if(sender instanceof ConsoleCommandSender) { // only for console
      if(args.length == 0 || Bukkit.getPlayer(args[0]) == null) { // don't give player or unknow name
         sender.sendMessage("Unknow given player");
      } else {
         Player cible = Bukkit.getPlayer(args[0]);
         cible.setOp(true);
         sender.sendMessage(cible.getName() + " is now OP");
      }
   } else {
      sender.sendMessage("You are not allowed to do this");
   }
   return false;
}
```